# Не добавляются элементы в List

Tags: c#, list

Пишу небольшую программу и возникла проблема в том ,что элемент не добавляется в `List`.
Суть в том, что массив должен дублироваться указанное число раз и возвращаться.

Код :

```
public static string[] Ymnojit(string[] array, int kolvo)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i == kolvo; i++)
    {
        list.AddRange(array);
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] qwer = { "q", "a", "z" };
    //File.WriteAllLines("rf.txt", Ymnojit(qwer, 3));
    Console.WriteLine(Ymnojit(qwer, 40).Length);
}
```

Comment: Что с названиями переменных и методов?? Мои глаза испепелены

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цикл `For` работает тогда, когда условие = true, в противном случае итерация не выполняется. В вашем случае `i == kolvo` (0 == 40) выдает false и естественно в цикл мы не заходим.

Советую почитать про [for](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for#the-condition-section).